# Draw graphs with DELPHI and Graviz

Tags: delphi

I#m going to use the project [GRAPH VIZ WITH DELPHI](http://kylecordes.com/2003/graphviz-delphi) for drawing graphs with DELPHI.

Compile is fine , but run gives error as shown below
[image: DUBUGGER ERROR],

what class to register and how ???  Never done this before

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks like you are missing a COM registration. The actual component is implemented in a COM component and needs to be registered with `regsvr32` or similar.

It looks like you are using WinGraphviz which can be downloaded here: http://wingraphviz.sourceforge.net/wingraphviz/. You need to get the compiled .dll installed and register it with `regsvr32`.

```
regsvr32.exe WinGraphviz.dll
```

The link above contains all the documentation you need to install and register the component.

Comment: Graphvizard is already on my Harddisk and installed ; rin regsvr32  with graphviz ?

Comment: You have to install and register WinGraphviz. Follow the link in my example and read all the documentation carefully.

Comment: I would also suggest to not use the `WINGRAPHVIZLib_TLB.pas` unit shipped with that example project but import the actual type library. That article is 11 years old.